# In Delphi does casting an object to its parent take a lot more memory?

Tags: delphi, memory, stream

I'm using a `TMemoryStream` and I need to pass it to `var` `TStream` procedure (external lib). I just cast my `TMemoryStream` to `TStream` like this:

```
var
    myStream: TMemoryStream;

begin
    //...
    ExternalProcedure(TStream(myStream)); //procedure ExternalProcedure(var AStream: TStream);
end;
```

Is this something to avoid? Does it take a lot of extra memory (the stream in question can be several MB)? My guess is no, but not 100% sure in Delphi.

Comment: It's something to avoid since there's no guarantee that what comes back is the right type.

Comment: Why are you casting your memory stream as `TStream`? Since `TMemoryStream` is derived from `TStream` you can pass it directly. In fat the reason why all stream variants are derived from `TStream` is to allow easy and unified way to access data from various different stream types.

Comment: A TMemoryStream is a TStream so the cast should not even be necessary at all. Do you get a compiler error? And by the way, if you really want to cast the value, you could use the "as" operator which will raise an exception if the item you cast cannot be caste to the type you ask.

Comment: @SilverWarior I can't pass it directly as it's a var parameter. I get "Types of actual and formal var parameters must be identical" if I don't cast it.

Comment: @ I can't "as" it either (again this is a var param). I get "Constant object cannot be passed as var parameter".

Comment: @David Heffernan But if in the external lib you know they just read the Stream, it's safe right? I guess they use a var parameter just to avoid copy the Stream.

Comment: @AlexV No. The `var` parameter means that the callee can change the reference. It's entirely possible that the author of the library doesn't understand reference types. What is the library?

Comment: @AlexV: You will not copy the stream object in any case, since classes in Delphi are reference types, as David says. So even if you use an ordinary value parameter (`ExternalProcedure(AStream: TStream)`), the only copy made is the pointer to the stream object. Consequently, the "external procedure" would still be able to modify the stream object. The only thing it can no longer do is to change the pointer passed to it. So if `myStream` points to the stream object at `$123456` before the invocation, it will point to `$123456` after the invocation as well. But the object there may have changed.

Comment: Note that you can declare a variable as `TStream` , but assign a TMemoryStream to it, in which case the cast isn't needed.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[MBo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/844416/mbo) [is right](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62527849/282848): this kind of cast will only instruct the compiler to assume that the type is the one you specify. This is essentially a cast that will make no additional code being generated. (But there are many exceptions when you cast *value* types.)

However, I generally would avoid this kind of unsafe cast. Here is an example of what can go wrong:

```
type
  TAnimal = class
    DNASequence: string;
  end;

  TSpider = class(TAnimal)
    MoultCount: Integer;
  end;

procedure ChangeAnimal(var AAnimal: TAnimal);
begin
  FreeAndNil(AAnimal);
  AAnimal := TAnimal.Create;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  Spider: TSpider;
begin
  Spider := TSpider.Create;
  try
    Spider.DNASequence := 'CTGA...';
    Spider.MoultCount := 3;
    ChangeAnimal(TAnimal(Spider));
    ShowMessage(Spider.MoultCount.ToString); // Oops! The `TSpider` variable
                                             // points to a `TAnimal` object!
  finally
    Spider.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 8):

Casting does not create new objects and correpondingly does not get new memory. It is just instruction for compiler to provide type compatibility